# How to copy columns from one sheet to another empty column in new sheet with value/format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy 8 columns (C18:J167 - with some merged cells) from Sheet "Assignments" to the next empty columns (starting with B4 in Sheet "Productivity Weekly".  Below is my code.   However, the problems I'm facing;

1. It pastes it starting in row B27154
2. It only pastes the values (not format)
3. The next time I run the macros, it puts the copied information in the same cells, not the next column. (so first time would be pasting in columns B:K, the next time columns L:S)

   Sub copycolumns()

   ```
   Dim lastrow As Long
   Dim LastColumn As Long

   With Sheets("Productivity Weekly")
       lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   End With


   Sheets("Assignments").Range("C18:j167").Copy
   Sheets("Productivity Weekly").Range("b" & LastColumn + 1 & lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.EnableEvents = True

   End Sub
   ```

I'm sure it's something easy that I've missed... either too much coffee, or not enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub sheet_1

Sheets("Assignments").Range("C18:j167").Copy

sheets.add

sheet2.range("a1").select

activesheet.paste
Sheets("Assignments").Range("C18:j167").clearcontents

end sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while it would appear that would copy the code, it would place it in a new sheet (where I was looking at placing it in an established sheet).  It also placed it in Cell A1, whereas I was looking for B4, and then subsequently the empty column cells.    Does this make sense of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.